# How to create index on single property using neo4j ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, neo4j

I am trying to create index on **ActiveNode** properties. when i tried with the code which is specified below , index is creating but it is throwing some **warning** like "**The constraint option is no longer supported (Defined on Neo4j for permalink)**" . How to create index on property without warning and error on nodes ?

```
class Neo4j
  include Neo4j::ActiveNode
  property :permalink, type: String, index: :exact 
end
```

And whenever i create a active node it should be automatically created after node creation , i am not appreciating functions with queries .
I am using "**neo4j-core**" gem on **ruby on rails** and version , edition is below:

```
{
    "edition": "community",
    "version": "3.4.1"
}
```